# My French is not of the quality it might/would be if I lived in France

Tags: prepositions, modal-verbs

1. My French is not of the quality it **might/would** **be** if I lived in France.

Is this sentence correct?

Also do we say:

My French is not **of** a certain quality.

Or

My French is not  a certain quality.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In (1) both choices are grammatically correct. They convey different meanings. With "would" you imply that the cultural immersion would definitely improve your French. With "might" you allow for the possibility that even among French speakers you might not put in the effort needed to speak and understand. Instead you might read the newspaper in English and talk only to your English speaking friends.

You can say

> My French is not of a certain quality.

That would suggest that it was not quite good enough for some things a native speaker could manage - idiomatic speech, accents, vernacular, technical prose.

You can't leave out the "of".

Comment: Is this OK: *My French is not of the quality it would be **of** if I lived in France*

Comment: No. In that sentence you omit the "of". But even without it  I think the sentence is awkward. I might say simply "My French is not as good as it would be if I lived in France".